# Import library DirectoryChooser in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import

Hello everyone I am French but I write in English, thank you for your indulgence

I develop my first android application with android studio

For my application I want to propose to choose a folder on phone

Not having found a native solution I try to use this library:
https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser

I did not succeed to import it helping me with readme.MD

I found a lot of topics that talk about it

like it: [how to import Android-DirectoryChooser][1] but no solve

I tried to add it with Maven Central but I did not succeed

I tried to import in module and i receive this error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'GROUP' for object of type org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeploy
```

Merci pour votre aide
Thanks for your help

The simple code :

```
package com.example.newtest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity;
import net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserConfig;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), DirectoryChooserActivity.class);

                final DirectoryChooserConfig config = DirectoryChooserConfig.builder()
                        .newDirectoryName("DirChooserSample")
                        .allowReadOnlyDirectory(true)
                        .allowNewDirectoryNameModification(true)
                        .build();

                chooserIntent.putExtra(DirectoryChooserActivity.EXTRA_CONFIG, config);
// REQUEST_DIRECTORY is a constant integer to identify the request, e.g. 0
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 2000);

            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 2000) {
            if (resultCode == DirectoryChooserActivity.RESULT_CODE_DIR_SELECTED) {
                Log.d("Directory", data.getStringExtra(DirectoryChooserActivity.RESULT_SELECTED_DIR));
            } else {
                // Nothing selected
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The debug:

```
07/15 16:40:29: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-G925F.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.newtest/com.example.newtest.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.newtest | com.example.newtest.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.newtest | com.example.newtest.test
Connected to process 16328 on device 'samsung-sm_g925f-1015fae86a033905'.
Connecting to com.example.newtest
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
E/Zygote: v2
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10475
    KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0005, [-1 -1 -4 -1 0 1]
I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.newtest 
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.newtest is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1423)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.newtest-2/lib/arm64
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2559)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:749)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void com.example.newtest.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:19)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.newtest-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.newtest-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2559)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:749)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void com.example.newtest.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:19)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=58
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@4007767[MainActivity] touchMode=true
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 506445808128} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 506445808128} hwInitialized=true
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 506445808128}
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@d7e98d1 nm : com.example.newtest ic=null
I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=70
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41cef36 nm : com.example.newtest ic=null
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@989c281[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment$10>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/gu/option/UnitFunction;
I/art:     at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment.newInstance(net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserConfig) (DirectoryChooserFragment.java:91)
        at void net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (DirectoryChooserActivity.java:38)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.gu.option.UnitFunction" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.newtest-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.newtest-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment.newInstance(net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserConfig) (DirectoryChooserFragment.java:91)
        at void net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (DirectoryChooserActivity.java:38)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment$11>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/gu/option/UnitFunction;
        at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment.newInstance(net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserConfig) (DirectoryChooserFragment.java:91)
        at void net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (DirectoryChooserActivity.java:38)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.gu.option.UnitFunction" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.newtest-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.newtest-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment.newInstance(net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserConfig) (DirectoryChooserFragment.java:91)
        at void net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (DirectoryChooserActivity.java:38)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.newtest, PID: 16328
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/gu/option/Option;
        at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment.<init>(DirectoryChooserFragment.java:61)
        at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment.newInstance(DirectoryChooserFragment.java:91)
        at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity.onCreate(DirectoryChooserActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.gu.option.Option" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.newtest-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.newtest-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment.<init>(DirectoryChooserFragment.java:61) 
        at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserFragment.newInstance(DirectoryChooserFragment.java:91) 
        at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity.onCreate(DirectoryChooserActivity.java:38) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.newtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:theme"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is the sdk version you re using ?

Comment: I use the Sdk 28

Comment: i meant the java sdk 7 , 8 or 11 or other

Comment: from THIRD_PARTY_README i use openJDK 8

Comment: i submitted an answer below , can you please check it out

Answer (score 1):

Okey based on those information you provide , give this a try

- Add this library to your dependencies gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation  'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:3.2@aar' // try this instead
}
```

- In your manifest file inside the application tag add this line

```
<application>
    <activity android:name="net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity" />
</application>
```

- Add these java lines

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 28

    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"



    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.transfertlocal2"

        minSdkVersion 22

        targetSdkVersion 28

        versionCode 1

        versionName "1.0"



        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

   ////add these lines 
   compileOptions
            {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }


    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217939/discussion-on-answer-by-taki-eddine-import-library-directorychooser-in-android-s).